# how can resolve checkin conflict issue in clearcase

Tags: java, exception, clearcase, checkin

When iam checkin the file then that is conflict with other latest version file.How can we resolve this issue?Iam unable to checkin the file sometimes in clearcase.

Answer (score 1):

That means someone already checked-in a new version, which means your own checkout file was an [unreserved one](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_checkout.htm).

See [`cleartool checkin`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_checkin.htm):

> If a more recent version of a selected resource is checked in, you must resolve any conflicts between your version and that version before the checkin can proceed.
>   This typically happens only if you are checking in a resource that was checked out unreserved.
>   If the differences do not conflict, ClearCase can merge them for you. If there are conflicting changes, you must perform a manual merge using ClearCase merge tools.

Updating the view can work, but you can also trigger the merge directly on that file.

- display the version tree
- right click on the latest version (which is not yours, and which is checked-in)
- select "merge to"
- click on your own unreserved checkedout version

That will merge the LATEST into your version without having to wait for a (potentially quite long) view update.
You will be able to check-in your version ofter that.

Comment: when iam clicking on version tree then i got one window.Then how can we select the latest version?Iam new to clearcase,so please provide better explanation.

Comment: @user1552438 you should see an "eye" referencing your currently checked-out version. And you should see a version with a number in it *after* your own version (again, your own version is the one with an eye beside it, and with no number in it). You should right click on the version after your own (the latest of the branch), and do the merge to your own version. No need to checkout anything since your are merge to your own - currently and already checked out - version.

Comment: See also http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0530&db=bks&srch=&fname=/SGI_EndUser/ClrC_UG/sgi_html/ch01.html#id5435964

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your working copy first. When you are updating your source control will try to merge your local changes with changes done by other developers. If it cannot it will mark conflicted points. Then you have to resolve these conflicts manually and mark as resolved. After that you can check your code in.

Good luck.

Comment: how can we update the working file?There is no update option when i give right click on file.